# Couchbase: Failed to start couchbase-server: timed out

Tags: couchbase

When my pc is connected with the network which other replicated couchbase servers also connected, the couchbase server which runs on my pc starts implicitly and no problem(localhost:8091 runs). But whenever I start my pc without connecting to network and then connect to localhost:8091, the couchbase server does not run. when I try to start by `sudo /etc/init.d/couchbase-server start`  It gives an error `Failed to start couchbase-server: timed out`  ..(the port 8091 is not being used by any other process) Why this happens ? Is there any configurations to modify ? My OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: Anything in the error log (under `/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs` by default)?

Comment: @DaveRigby . There are many types of logs. Can you specify which one you meant?

Comment: I cleared out my logs and the only log that was there was start.log and it was empty.

Comment: @Débora Did you find out what the problem was? I am facing the same issue. Failed to start couchbase-server : timed out

Answer (score 0):

> When my pc is connected with the network which other replicated
>   couchbase servers also connected

Can you clarify? Your PC instance is part of a cluster? If yes, it might be the issue.

Say you have a Couchbase cluster of 3 nodes (A - B - C) and your computer is A.
When you are offline:

- A doesn't see B and C, and since it has less nodes than the majority (3/2 = 2 for majority), it doesn't start.
- B and C don't see A, but since they have the majority of the cluster (2 nodes), they keep working, and consider A as down (thus trigger the failover mechanisms)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ip_start (/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/ip_start) and put your machine ip

```
/etc/init.d/couchbase-server start
```